# Сериализация и десериализация xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialize, сериализация

Подскажите, как легко и быстро список содержащий элементы пользовательского класса сериализовать в xml-файл, а затем вынуть его оттуда?

Comment: Легко и быстро не выйдет, сериализация — довольно неприятная тема.

А вы экземпляры класса уже умеете сериализовать?

Comment: @Егор Шатов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Допустим, вам нужен xml вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<YourSettings>
  <YourSetting>
    <YourName>Name</YourName>
  </YourSetting>
</YourSettings>
```

создадим класс `YourSettings` с полем Name:

```
[Serializable()]
public class YourSettings
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "YourName")]
    public string YourName { get; set; }
}
```

и сериализуемую коллекцию элементов этого класса:

```
[Serializable()]
public class YourSettingsCollection
{
    public YourSettingsCollection() { YourSettings = new List<YourSettings>(); }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "YourSettings")]
    public List<YourSettings> YourSettingsList { get; set; }
 }
```

тогда на старте приложения можно написать что-то типа:

```
YourSettingsCollection _settings;

void Read()
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//имя_файла.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourSettingsCollection), new XmlRootAttribute("YourSettings"));
        _settings = (YourSettingsCollection)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
 }
```

таким образом, переменная `_settings` будет содержать коллекцию элементов из вашего config-файла.